# Get billing address info on checkout order review step in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7, checkout

I want to display to user the address, that will be used for billing, in the last step of One Page Checkout in Magento. I tried the following method in file `review\info.phtml`:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                                      ->getShippingAddress()
                                      ->getData();
```

But when I go to the review order step, I am redirected to shopping cart page. Maybe I need to insert the code in other file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had once the same problem. Try this:

```
<?php
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();
print_r($billAddress->getData());
?>
```

P.S. You are trying to get shipping address when you want billing.